# Controller rspec that is not working well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in my rspec (aim is to test whether the controller function is working properly).

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe CollaborationsController do

include TestFactories

 before do
  # @user = create(:user)
  @user = authenticated_user
  # @wiki = create(:wiki, user: @user)
  @wiki = authenticated_wiki
  sign_in @user
 end

 describe "#create" do
  expect (@user.collaborations.find_by_wiki_id(@wiki.id)).to be_nil
  post :create, {wiki_id: @wiki.id}
  expect(@user.collaborations.find_by_wiki_id(@wiki.id)).not_to be_nil
 end

 describe "#destroy" do
  expect (@user.collaborations).to eq (0)
  post :create, {wiki_id: @wiki.id}
  expect (@user.collaborations).to eq (1)

  delete :destroy, {wiki_id: @wiki.id, id: collaborations.id}
  expect(@user.collaborations.find_by_wiki_id(@wiki.id)).not_to be_nil
 end

 end


 def authenticated_user
  user = User.new(email: "email#{rand}@fake.com", password: 'password')
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save
  user
 end


 def authenticated_wiki
  wiki = Wiki.new(title: "Dit is de title", body: 'password')
  wiki.save
  wiki
 end
```

When I run it however I get the following error:

```
 undefined method `collaborations' for nil:NilClass
```

This seems kind of strange to me cause when I try out the relations in the console everything works fine.

u = User.first
u.collaborations gives this fe

```
 collaboration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "collaborations".* FROM "collaborations"   WHERE "collaborations"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Collaboration id: 18,     user_id: 1, wiki_id: 1, created_at: "2015-02-26 08:54:36", updated_at: "2015-02-26   08:54:36">, #<Collaboration id: 19, user_id: 1, wiki_id: 1, created_at: "2015-02-   26 09:07:19", updated_at: "2015-02-26 09:07:19">]> 
 2.1.5 :003 >
```

Any quick thoughts on what im doing wrong here?

Comment: You're calling `collaborations` on nil - track down where that is (there should be backtrace to go with that error) and you'll be halfway there

Comment: Jes, I understand that im calling collaborations on nill. However I can call collaborations on user in rails c so the fault should be in my syntax right?

Comment: Where is your `it` in your `describe` block???

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your code is invalid. You are putting the test code within `describe` block, but it should be wrapped wit `it`. Try formatting this:

```
describe "#create" do
  expect (@user.collaborations.find_by_wiki_id(@wiki.id)).to be_nil
  post :create, {wiki_id: @wiki.id}
  expect(@user.collaborations.find_by_wiki_id(@wiki.id)).not_to be_nil
end

describe "#destroy" do
  expect (@user.collaborations).to eq (0)
  post :create, {wiki_id: @wiki.id}
  expect (@user.collaborations).to eq (1)

  delete :destroy, {wiki_id: @wiki.id, id: collaborations.id}
  expect(@user.collaborations.find_by_wiki_id(@wiki.id)).not_to be_nil
end
```

like this:

```
describe "#create" do
  it "sets the collaborations" do
    expect (@user.collaborations.find_by_wiki_id(@wiki.id)).to be_nil
    post :create, {wiki_id: @wiki.id}
    expect(@user.collaborations.find_by_wiki_id(@wiki.id)).not_to be_nil
  do
end

describe "#destroy" do
  it "destroys collaborator" do
    expect (@user.collaborations).to eq (0)
    post :create, {wiki_id: @wiki.id}
    expect (@user.collaborations).to eq (1)

    delete :destroy, {wiki_id: @wiki.id, id: collaborations.id}
    expect(@user.collaborations.find_by_wiki_id(@wiki.id)).not_to be_nil
  end
end
```

Sometimes lack of `it`'s leads to strange behaviour, and misleading error messages.

Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `before(:each)`

Also I would like to do something like `let(:user){ authenticated_user }` in describe block.

And do one **expectation** in one `it` block